# Eletrolytic rust removal

Tags: electrolysis

I've seen quite a few youtube videos about electrolysis for rust removal. The process seems to be effective. My question is: how does it work?

I get that the water is ionised so we have O- and OH+ ions. I get that O2 is liberated at the anode. But what is going on at the cathode to release the rust? Is the rust chemically changed or is the rust somehow chemically released from the parent metal?

I'm a (rusty - graduated 1981) physicist, so don't hold back on the answer.

Comment: XRD of rust shows Fe3 O4 -H2O mostly ,and several similar compounds . Very rarely Fe2O3  ; at ambient temperature it is diagnostic of fretting corrosion.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik rust ≠ $\ce{Fe2O3}$.

Comment: You mean $\ce{H+ and OH-}$ ions, right? Ideally, electrolysis would reduce rust to iron, and the iron would be in the same spot it was before rusting. However, nobody has figured out how to do that, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Electrolytic rust removal appears more like a semi-hoax to me. I think it is more like a mechanical removal of rust layer. As we dip a rusty object in sodium bicarb solution and you pass cathodic currents, we would see bubbling of hydrogen gas from the rusty object. These bubbles apparently help to loosen up the tight rust layer (bottom up). The cathodic current may also reduce some iron oxide.

The anode, which most videos suggest should be made of iron, is also useless in a sodium bicarbonate solution. Any inert conductor would have worked like a graphite anode. The reason is that the iron from the anode must go into the solution, if it were a true electroplating. However, in most videos iron oxides from the anod float as a precipitate of iron hydroxides. The whole solution turns rusty. Finally, people suggest a mechanical brushing or polishing. I am sure if a rusted object is polished with an abrasive, the results would be the same as electrochemical "rust" removal.

Now some over-the-counter rust stain removers are quite effective. They contain powerful reducing and perhaps some chelating agents. No, it is not oxalic acid, if that is coming to mind. These reducing agents immediately remove the rust by chemical means, but the iron surface is no longer shiny (greyish black). One has to polish it again to look shiny.